# Promotion of npm package with dependencies to Release view

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops

Imagine an [Azure DevOps feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/artifacts-overview?view=azure-devops) (MyFeed) of npm packages with two views: Local and Release. This feed has an upstream source https://registry.npmjs.org/. Two packages (@scope/a and @scope/b) are already published and they are in Local view. Both of them directly depend on **prop-types** package from npmjs:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    ...
  }
```

Packages "a" and "b" are installed, builded (Storybook, i.e.) and deployed to some test environment for review. During installation of the packages their dependency prop-types is [saved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/package-graph?view=azure-devops) from upstream to the **Local** view of the feed.

Let's assume that package A passes review and is [promoted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/views?view=azure-devops) to @Release view. Then I try to install it into the main project, which is connected to MyFeed@Release. But installation fails, because prop-types is still in Local view:

```
$ npm i @scope/a
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://*/*/_packaging/MyFeed%40Release/npm/registry/prop-types - NotFound
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'prop-types@^15.7.2' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of '@scope/a'
```

The only way to start using package "a" is to promote all it's dependencies to the same view (package "b" still installs correctly after that). But shouldn't it be done automatically? Or is there a workaround to use unpromoted (Local) upstream packages? There are could be plenty of dependencies from public packages from npmjs, which can hardly be managed manually.

Maybe I should create another feed, connected to npmjs and use it "in front" of MyFeed, like so:
**npmjs** <- **MyUpstreamFeed** (with Local view only) <- **MyFeed** (not directly connected to npmjs).

Comment: Proposed solution with MyUpstreamFeed will not work too. Packages from npmjs should be *preliminarily* saved to MyUpstreamFeed, otherwise it will return 404 to MyFeed. I've tested it myself and the result corresponds to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/package-graph?view=azure-devops#example-constructing-the-set-of-available-packages).